# How to format this output in JScrollPane?

Tags: java, formatting, format, jscrollpane

currently I have this output:

```
State: FL 
Name: Telephone
Code: xx-xxx
Manufacturer: Motorola
Price: 254.99

State: NY 
Name: Computer
Code: xx-xxx
Manufacturer: Motorola
Price: 756.99
```

I need this output:

```
Product      Code     Purchase Date     Quantity    Price       Manufacturer    State
Telephone   xx-xxx       01/20/2013        10       254.99      Motorola          FL
Computer    xx-xxx       01/06/2013        15       756.99      CBS               NY
```

I have to use a Use scrollable window to display the output, so I am using scrollpane for it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [JTable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html). It's designed to provide tabular data

[image: JTable]

*Picture from How to use Tables*